# How to import tilde delimited file using Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql

I want to import a tilde delimited file into MySQL using Sequel Pro. It looks like Sequel Pro only allows: `|`, `,`, `;`, `\t` and I cannot find anywhere allows me to configure the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down selection for Sequel Pro can be typed into it; click inside the select field (dont click the down arrow) and type in tilde. Tested on v1.0.2.